# Firebase Database to UITableView Cell Problems

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app that uses the firebase database to display two different child databases within one cell. So, since my first child database is called "Name", it would be the main text of the cell, and the second child database, "ImageURL", would be the subtitled text of the cell.

I am not able to figure out why whenever I try to get the second child database to the table view cell, it doesn't work. I either get an Index out of Range error, or the second child database doesn't even show up at all.

Here is my code:

Variables:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myNameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

var ref: DatabaseReference!
var myNameList:[String] = []
var myList:[String] = []
var handle:DatabaseHandle!
var nameHandle: DatabaseHandle!
```

Button Code when SAVE button is pressed:

```
@IBAction func saveBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    if myNameField.text != "" {
        ref?.child("Name").childByAutoId().setValue(myNameField.text)
        myNameField.text = ""

    if myTextField.text != "" {
            ref?.child("ImageURL").childByAutoId().setValue(myTextField.text)
            myTextField.text = ""
        }
    }

}
```

TableView Function NumberOfRowsInSection code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myList.count
}
```

TableView Function CellForRowAtIndexPath code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = myNameList[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = myList[indexPath.row]
```

ViewDidLoad code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    handle = ref?.child("ImageURL").observe(.childAdded, with:{ (DataSnapshot) in
        if let item = DataSnapshot.value as? String{
            self.myList.append(item)
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
    nameHandle = ref?.child("Name").observe(.childAdded, with:{ (DataSnapshot) in
        if let nameItem = DataSnapshot.value as? String{
            self.myList.append(nameItem)
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })


}
```

My Main.Storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice a couple of things that might be causing the issue.

In the `cellForRowAt` function, you are populating `textLabel` with an array called `myNameList`, and populating `detailTextLabel` with an array called `myList`. However, when you're loading the data in `viewDidLoad`, you're appending both contents to `myList`. Probably a copy/paste error, but I think one of those should be `myNameList`.

Also, your data structure is flawed. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, based on how you're indexing the rows (using `indexPath.row`), you're assuming the items will always come in pairs and the two refs will always have the same amount of children. But based on `saveBtn`, I can easily just enter a `name` and not an `imageURL`, and it'll just save the `name`, and the whole database is now mismatched. I'd suggest having a single child ref called `items`, where each one has a `name` and an `imageURL`.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to implement images into a firebase database, instead of just an image URL?

Comment: Firebase Storage can provide storage for your images. You convert them to `Data` and upload them using Firebase Storage, then it spits back a URL that you can use to download the image when you want it. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/start